# Is portable class libraries are beneficial for window 8 store apps

Tags: wcf, architecture, windows-8

Is portable class libraries are beneficial for window 8 store apps. 
I am trying to create an architecture for Window 8 App in which i have WCF Restful service for data. My problem is i don't want to create proxy classes for each entity in Window 8 project, so i want to use Datalayer in which i have all entities and business logic's, this data layer has reference in wcf service which return me xml/json  result. Now i need to consume this service in Window 8 App for which i need to  map data with proxy classes that i don't want to create.

So my problem is can we refer datalayer to window 8 app project, at this time i found it is impossible as Window 8 App project doesn't support System.Data.
or, can any one tell me what pattern should i use to achieve my goal.

Does portable class libraries will help me out of it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Read this : http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-portable-class-libraries and this : [How to call REST services from Portable Class Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196665/how-to-call-rest-services-from-portable-class-library)

Comment: yes i try to make it i am using EF, but Portable Class libraries doesn't support it though so am confused how to do it

Comment: Try to search in Google and Stack Overflow, then do some code and then post what you facing. check [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/access-data-with-rest-in-windows-8-apps/240144594) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917736/how-to-work-with-portable-class-library-and-ef-code-first)

Comment: okey thanks, i am looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable class libraries are used to solve the problem of sharing backend code (business logic/data layer) between multiple frontend client apps (Windows 7, Windows 8, Silverlight, Windows Phone, and Xbox 360).  So if you were writing both a Windows 8 app and something else (say a Windows Phone app), you could put your backend logic in a portable class library, and it would build to an assembly that you could reference from both your Windows 8 app and your Windows Phone app.

So, portable class libraries are probably not the tool that you need to solve your problem, which is needing to consume a service in a Window 8 App.  If you do a Bing search for "consume json in windows 8", there are a lot of results that can help with this.